# How to configure PAX S300 Simulator with Odoo14 POS

Tags: odoo-14

I am trying to configure PAX S300 Simulator with Odoo14 POS but no success. Can anyone help how to configure it.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide details and clarification.

Comment: Hello Merlin, 
Thanks for responding. I am totally blank about how to use the Simulator. When i open the simulator App it shows "Activate Online Connection Error". I can access the other menu pressing f1 key. I want to know the IP address and Port to connect with this simulator, so that i can send the Payment request from POS to it.

Comment: Please update your question with those details. But I think it's a prety wide subject and suspect it has nothing to do with programming and doesn't belong on stackoverflow.